# Add constraints to neo4j node based on node property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher, constraints

I am adding constraints to a neo4j database using Cypher constraints and want to create a constraint which only applies to a subset of a node type.

I can create a constraint that a `foo` field must exist on `Entity` with

`CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:Entity) ASSERT EXISTS (e.foo)`

but instead, I want to constrain only nodes with a given field. e.g

`CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:Entity {constrain_flag:true) ASSERT EXISTS (e.foo)`

For example, I may have two nodes like

`(e:Entity { foo: 'bar' , constrain_flag: true })` and

`(e:Entity { constrain_flag: false })`

I only want the constraint that `e.foo` must exist to apply to the `Entity` where `constrain_flag = true`, so both of these should be allowed. However,

`(e:Entity { constrain_flag: false })` should throw an exception.

Is there a way to do this currently with cypher and neo4j?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a flag property, you can just [add an additional label](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/set/#set-set-a-label-on-a-node) (say, `ConstrainedEntity`) to `Entity` nodes that should be constrained. Queries can continue to use just the `Entity` label.

For example:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (ce:ConstrainedEntity) ASSERT EXISTS (ce.foo)
```

To create a "flagged" `Entity`:

```
CREATE (e:Entity:ConstrainedEntity {id: 111, foo: 'bar'})
```

To "flag" an existing `Entity`:

```
MATCH (e:Entity)
WHERE e.id = 123
SET e:ConstrainedEntity
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could nest node types like that. That's amazing, thanks so much!